# Is Neutronium possible?

Tags: atomic-physics, neutrons

Now I am not talking about neutron stars here. I am talking about a supposed substance with only neutrons in the nucleus.

All atoms of this category would have a negative charge and negative charge is normally stabilized by positive charge. Since there is no positive charge here I would think the gravity between the neutron and the electron would be so strong that electron capture happens in the neutron giving you a very unstable negatively charged particle which suddenly goes into beta decay mode and gives you once again a neutron and an electron.

[image: Neutronium]

So is it actually possible for a neutron to have an electron around it without going through electron capture?

Comment: Gravity is a completely irrelevant force in this case. The interaction energy between the magnetic moments of neutron and electron is far, far larger. The neutron has no measurable electric dipole moment, as far as I know, but there should be a higher oder polarization term which should also lead to an effective potential, but I don't know if it is attractive or not.

Comment: Hmmm... I just ran the numbers... if I am not mistaken it seems gravity will be stronger than the magnetic dipole term at distances of $>10^{11}m$ or 100 million km, i.e. the distance between Earth and sun... and the acceleration of the electron due to the neutron's mass will be on the order of $10^{-59}m/s^2$. That's going to be a long wait for that electron to circle the neutron even once...

Comment: There have been extensive searches for a bound state between two neutrons and they have all been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3):

These atoms would not have a negative charge, they would have zero charge.  They would have no electrons at all. You could imagine (if they were **far** from anything else) an electron orbiting a neutron under gravity.  The attraction is so weak that any other matter anywhere close would disturb it.  The real question is whether a clump of neutrons could be stable.  Without gravity, the answer is no.  We have explored all the small nuclei looking for stability without success.  We know well what ratio of neutrons to protons is the most stable.  It starts at $1:1$ and increases slowly from there, but is a long way from infinity.